# Adding jQuery to a view (exposed filter: search terms)

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'd like to add some jQuery (for search highlighting) to my Drupal 7 Views with exposed search terms filter. The point is that when a user clicks a search terms (or terms) the jQuery then highlights those words they searched for in the returned results.

I created the following preprocess function in my template.php file:

```
    // add jquery.highlight-5.js just to the search views page
    function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == '8' && arg(3) == null) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . 
'/js/jquery.highlight-5.js');
      }
    }
```

But as I put this together I realize I don't know what to put in arg(1) for my Drupal View. Anyone know how to find out the 'nodeid' of the Drupal View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use hook views pre render instead.](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

```
function themename_views_pre_render(&$view) {

   if ($view->name == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/js/jquery.highlight-5.js');
   } 
}
```

- replace **themename** with your theme name
- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** with your machine name

[image]